# Print a signed 64-bit integer in hexadecimal and octal

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that prints a **signed** 64-bit variable in hexadecimal and octal format. I searched online for the format specifier, but I only found results for **unsigned** 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifiers `%o` and `%x` indeed are defined for unsigned integral values only. In case of a signed input, and if you want to show a signed value like `-234` with a "sign" in hex as well, e.g. `-ea`, you'll have to handle signed values separately.
Otherwise, if you want a negative value to show up as the proper unsigned conversion (i.e. the two's complement representation), simply cast it to `unsigned`:

```
int main() {

    int input = -234;
    if (input < 0) {
       printf("-%x\n", (unsigned)(-input));
    } else {
       printf("%x\n", (unsigned)input);
    }
    
    printf("%x\n", (unsigned)input);
}
```

Output:

```
-ea
ffffff16
```

Comment: Better code for the first `printf` is `printf("-%x\n", - (unsigned) input);`. This both has the right type and avoids overflow, since the negation is done in the `unsigned` type, which will wrap.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: According to the C standard, two's complement representation is not mandatory (cf. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p2). I don't think that other representations than two's complement are actually used; at least in theory it could be the case. So I reverted some of the changes back; `-input` cannot overflow if we check `if (input < 0)`, and it seems more natural for me to write then `(unsigned)(-input)`. And I reverted the "i.e." to "most likely" and added a note.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: you are right; the signed and unsigned integer conversion in 6.3. specifies 2's complement...